# How to delete entity when "health <= 0"?

Tags: java

Ive been followin an online tutorial for a top down shooter game, but the tut is unfinished (and I dont see the creator continuing it), so Id like to complete it myself. So far, the tutorial has helped me to give the player health and a string above it to show how much health, but nothing happens when health gets to and goes below 0. It just goes down in the increment I set. Id like the game to close when there is no more health, so how would I go about doing this?

This is what happens when the player gets hit by an enemy bullet:

```
    private void playerBulletCollision(){
    for (Bullet b:mobBullets){
            if (b.collisionBox.intersects(player.collisionBox)){
                player.health -= b.damage;
                b.isAlive = false;
                break;
            }

    }
}
```

And this is what happens when player bullet hits enemy

```
    private void mobBulletCollision(){
    for (Bullet b:bullets){
        for (Entity m: mobs){
            if (b.collisionBox.intersects(m.collisionBox)){
                m.health -= b.damage;
                b.isAlive = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so how can I make it so the game ends when player health is no more? Sorry if my explanation isnt clear or the code I showed isnt enough/not relevant. Tell me and Ill fix it to the best of my abilities.

Thank you

Edit: I tried to make it so it checks to see if health <= 0 and if it does it despawns:

```
    private void playerBulletCollision(){
    for (MobBullet b:mobBullets){
            if (b.collisionBox.intersects(player.collisionBox)){
                player.health -= b.damage;
                b.isAlive = false;
                break;                  
            }
        if(player.health <=0)
            player.isAlive = false;
    }
}
```

It didnt work.

Edit 2: This is the process to remove the dead enemies. I think because there is no such thing for the player, player.health = false; does nothing.

```
private void removeDead(){
    for (int i = 0; i <bullets.size(); i++){
        if (bullets.get(i).isAlive == false )
            bullets.remove(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <mobs.size(); i++){
        if (mobs.get(i).isAlive == false )
            mobs.remove(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <mobBullets.size(); i++){
        if (mobBullets.get(i).isAlive == false )
            mobBullets.remove(i);
    }


    bullets.trimToSize();
    mobs.trimToSize();
    mobBullets.trimToSize();
}
```

How should this piece be modified to incorporate the player?

Comment: Every collision you should check if `health` is smaller or equal then 0, if so you end the game

Comment: Tried that, nothing happens.

Comment: please show the code of what u tried

Comment: In playerBulletCollision(); after the closing } after "break;" I put 

    if(player.health <=0)
       player.isAlive = false;

To test if it actually does anything, as the enemies follow the same sort of condition. (sorry dont know how to format in these comments)

Comment: What is b.damage? Have you initialized it to something, or is it 0?

Comment: @RobBor: If you add additional information you shouldn't add it in comments. Edit your question and add the details there.

Comment: @Patrick b.damage is the damage dealt by the bullet of the mob or player, and they are both set to deal 10 damage. I will edit original post now, thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "I dont know if its in the correct place"? Does it work or does it not?

Comment: When you edit your question with the new code it's easier to help you.

Comment: @Patrick sorry: It didnt work

Comment: You should place the check *after* the loop, not for each bullet... If you hit a bullet you break out of the loop, and hence doesn't check for player health, is that really what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this. On a collision you decrement the `health` and after the loop you check the player `health` if this is `<=0` you set `isAlive` to `false`.

```
private void playerBulletCollision(){
for (MobBullet b:mobBullets){
        if (b.collisionBox.intersects(player.collisionBox)){
            player.health -= b.damage;
            b.isAlive = false;
            break;                  
        }
}

if(player.health <=0){
    player.isAlive = false;
}
```

Comment: The health continued to decrease with nothing happening if it went under 0. Also the bullet has stopped disappearing but this is because b.isAlive = false; line was taken out.

Comment: It did not work either.  I acheived the same results as last time. The health continued to decrease and did not stop after <=0

Comment: What happens if you debug? Does the debugger jump out of the loop after a collision and goes to `if(player.health <=0)` or is there something else going on?